# Removing latest item from drop list

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on angular drag and drop. My Code is as follows

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-higfzm?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts

The item which I am dropping will always be dropped at end of done list. I want to have a "X" mark on latest item dropped(suppose user drags and drops item1 then "X" should be on items1 and if user drags and drops item2 then "X" should be only on item2) so that if user wishes user can click on "X" and item is removed from done list and get back to the "TO DO" list again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the changes. So I am pasting the HTML and TS code here. I am unsure if the code saves on the stackblitz.

In component file `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  moveItemInArray,
  transferArrayItem
} from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop connected sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: "cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example",
  templateUrl: "cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css"]
})
export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingExample  implements OnInit{
  todo = [
    "Get to work",
    "Pick up groceries",
    "Go home",
    "Fall asleep",
    "Walk Dog",
    "Stretch",
    "Code Stuff",
    "Drag Stuff",
    "Drop Stuff",
    "Run",
    "Walk"
  ];




  done = ["Get up", "Brush teeth", "Take a shower", "Check e-mail", "Walk dog"];

  public DroppedListLength;  // tracking the length of the list


ngOnInit() {
  this.DroppedListLength = this.done.length;
}

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      console.log("first if..");
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        this.done.length
      );
      console.log("second if..");
      this.DroppedListLength = this.done.length; // update the list length for any drop
    }
  }
// just add a function to remove the last added value
  removeLastDroppedItem() {
    this.done.pop();
this.DroppedListLength = this.done.length; // you can add this to keep track of last item in the list
  }
}
```

In html `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html` you only need to add a button and associate its click with the above function:

```
<div class="example-container">
    <h2>To do</h2>

    <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]" class="example-list"
     (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="example-container">
    <h2>Done</h2>

    <div cdkDropList #doneList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="done" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]" class="example-list"
     (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done; let i = index" cdkDrag>{{item}}
      <span *ngIf="i+1 === DroppedListLength" (click)="removeLastDroppedItem()">X</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: you can update these files and it should work as intended.

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: it is working fine. Just a additional question suppose user added two items, item 1 and item 2 and user clicks "X" on item 2 then item2 gets back to To Do list. what to do if I want to have "X" on second last that is item1 after item2 is removed?

Comment: nops I want "X" on the newly added items only. It is showing cross on already present items of done list when we delete newly added items

Comment: I want "X" only on newly added items. If newly added items are removed from done list. Cross should not be shown for already present items

Comment: For that to work, you need to flag the values in the array to work. I believe for that you should ask a new question as primarily your question doesn't ask this. And I believe what is being asked in the question is answered. I hope you can accept the answer and repost the new question for your query. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052520/getting-count-of-dropped-items-and-removing-recent-items-from-drop-list/67054088#67054088 I have posted a new question for this. Request you to please answer there. I will close this question

Comment: I will post my answer, you can close this. I will take a look a this.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to store the index of last element and then apply logic in the template
[Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-1xujft?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: it is working fine. Just a additional question suppose user added two items, item 1 and item 2 and user clicks "X" on item 2 then item2 gets back to To Do list. what to do if I want to have "X" on second last that is item1 after item2 is removed

Comment: I would store some unique identifier about last added items somewhere (array, map, set) and then do some simple check in template whether to display "X"